# Vba macros in Excel - Range.Validation.Type Causes 1004

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to prevent pasting over a dropdown in Excel. The code I came up with is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'turn off events so this routine is not continuously fired

    Set BoroughTrainingTookPlaceIn = Range("BoroughTrainingTookPlaceIn")
    Set StartTimeOfSession = Range("StartTimeOfSession")
    Set TypeOfSession = Range("TypeOfSession")
    Set BikeabilityLevelRatingBeforeTraining = Range("BikeabilityLevelRatingBeforeTraining")
    Set BikeabilityLevelRatingAfterTraining = Range("BikeabilityLevelRatingAfterTraining")


    If RangesIntersect(Target, BoroughTrainingTookPlaceIn) Then
        PreventPaste (BoroughTrainingTookPlaceIn)
    ElseIf RangesIntersect(Target, StartTimeOfSession) Then
        PreventPaste (StartTimeOfSession)
    ElseIf RangesIntersect(Target, TypeOfSession) Then
        PreventPaste (TypeOfSession)
    ElseIf RangesIntersect(Target, BikeabilityLevelRatingBeforeTraining) Then
        PreventPaste (BikeabilityLevelRatingBeforeTraining)
    ElseIf RangesIntersect(Target, BikeabilityLevelRatingAfterTraining) Then
        PreventPaste (BikeabilityLevelRatingAfterTraining)
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
'   Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
 Function RangesIntersect(ByVal Range1 As Range, ByVal Range2 As Range) As Variant
    Dim intersectRange As Range
    Set intersectRange = Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2)
    If intersectRange Is Nothing Then
        RangesIntersect = False
    Else
        RangesIntersect = True
    End If
End Function
 Private Function PreventPaste(ByVal Target As Range) As Variant
    If Not HasValidation(Target) Then
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Invalid value. Please chose a value from the dropdown"
    End If
End Function
```

The line `x = r.Validation.Type` is causing Error 1004 when I try to copy by dragging a cell in the dataValdiation Range. I am using named ranges.

I looked trough the already opened questions but didn't find answer there. All help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I was trying to cut it and not to copy and paste it by dragging. Still for newbies like me might be useful to record the macro first and see what you are actually doing

Comment: How is `PreventPaste` being invoked? Presumably triggered by one of the sheet's event procedures. Can you include that code as well?

Comment: What is `r`? If it's a `Range` you'll need to specify this in the parameters of the function, e.g. `HasValidation(r as Range)`

Comment: Given you've not provided your usage of PreventPaste it's difficult to know what is being put into it. My assumption would be it is designed as a single cell function and you're trying to pass in a range of cells. try adding a `for each cell in target.cells` loop to the PreventPaste function. Additionally there are some other red flags here, the use of `on error resume next` with no return to normal, and x is not dimmed either.

Comment: @David Zemens - I updated the queston
@ Jordan Yes, I figured that out - I added it but no change

Comment: The use of `On Error Resume Next` should definitely prevent the 1004 from raising in this case (it occurs if `r` has no validation assigned). I'm unable to replicate this error.

Comment: Function doesn't fail on a multi-cell range, although it may return unexpected results if some cells have and others do not have validation rule.

Comment: @Zerk - I dimmed the x, how do I return to normal after `on error resume next`, I am new to vba

David Zemens - It happens when i try to copy cell with data validation to another cell with data validation in the same range by dragging

Comment: @dstoyanova to disable the handler of `resume next` use `on error goto 0`. In this case it isn't breaking anything but is good practice to only use resume next minimally and disable/replace it as soon as possible, otherwise it can mask errors that would otherwise be noticed.

Comment: Zerk - I am using the thrown error to determine if the range has data validation, if the error is 0 it has, if other then it doesn't, but it is throwing 1004 despite that the copied cell has data validation